# How does the audience visualise a WFS in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I recently started learning Geoserver. WMS is straighforward but in case of WFS, I have read a lot of user manuals and training pages but I cannot figure out how does the actual visual map served out to the audience in the end?

I read everywhere that we make a query through an URL and get an XML document as output but i'm sure this XML is not for the audience.

The audience will be making queries in some point and click interface next to the map and directly looking at the results in the map right? So how is this interface served to them?

Everywhere I read its the same- queries through URL and output in the form of XML. This cannot be what the audience is supposed to see?

Can someone please point me to a resource which explains this? Or does this have something to do with coding the visual final map with Java separately?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Well the question is divided into many sub questions but in essence they all related to only one general question- how to visually serve the the maps to audience.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to visualize WMS and WMTS are the protocols to use.

WFS is meant to transfer raw data with full geometries and attributes, which a client software (not a human) can then either visualize on its own (try for example QGis as a WFS client), analyze and eventually edit, saving back the changes via the WFS Transaction call.

OGC in general provides different protocols for different purposes, for example:

- Find services, layers and data: CSW
- Visualize: WMS and WMTS
- Download raw data for local use: WFS and WCS
- Perform server side spatial analysis: WPS

Comment: Ok so if the client is able to visualise, analyse and edit this raw data is not decided by Geoserver. All Geoserver can do is enable the WFS/WPS service for that data and send it and then leave it to the client to be able to do further steps. Ive seen some webmaps where I on the client machine can perform basic stuff like filtering features, buffering etc. So I was wondering if such an app can be made by Geoserver alone. But from what I understand now, Geoserver serves raw data which should then be somehow visualised and analysed by the client using other ways like QGIS or JavaScript.

Comment: Excactly... The client often is also a browser (webgis) where you have a combination of both, visualisation and data processing. For example when you draw something in a webgis you may have a WMS as background and some forms that query a WFS. This is also an application and nothing magical done by Geoserver. But this kind of appication is often on the same server and creates the dynamic web page the users see in their browsers.